# Handling PCI read/write to configuration space in a QEMU device

Tags: c, linux-kernel, qemu, pci

I'm working on implementing a simple PCI device in QEMU and a kernel driver for it, and I have some trouble with handling pci_read/write_config_* function calls from the device side.

Unlike simple rw operations on a memory mapped bar, where the MemoryRegionOps callbacks receive the exact offset used by the driver, the config_read/write callbacks implemented as members in PCIDevice struct, receive an address that went through some manipulations/mapping that I have a hard time understanding.

Following the code path up to pci_config_host_read/write in QEMU sources, and the same in the kernel side for pci_read/write_config_* functions, didn't provide any clear answers.

Can anyone help me understand how to extract the config offset used by the driver when calling the pci config rw functions?

Comment: Why do you want to know the address used by the driver? All you need is the 12-bit offset into the device’s config space.

Comment: I guess my question was unclear. I'm talking about the address argument used by the pci config rw functions, which IS a 12 bit offset, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your PCI device model up to implement the QEMU PCIDevice config_read and config_write methods, the addresses passed to them should be the offsets into the PCI config space (ie starting with the standard 0 == PCI_VENDOR_ID, 2 == PCI_DEVICE_ID, 4 == PCI_COMMAND and so on, and any device-specific stuff after the 64 bytes of standardized config space).

Comment: I can see from the printouts in config_read and config_write that this is the case for those standard words when the driver is probed/removed, but for some reason, when I'm trying to write to custom addresses, such as:
`pci_write_config_dword(pdev, 0xFF0, data)`
I can see the rw callbacks called 3 times, in this order: write->read->write, with the address value: 4, 13, 13, respectively. For other addresses, the callbacks are not even called. I guess I'm missing something fundamental about how QEMU handles PCI devices, or maybe even how PCI works in general.

Comment: 0xff0 is outside the 256 bytes of plain PCI config space -- is your device model definitely advertising itself correctly as a PCI-E device with that much config space? Do you still see weird behaviour for accesses within the first 256 bytes?

Comment: Actually yes, I'm trying to emulate a PCI-E device. I'm not sure if I correctly advertised this device as such, but I did set TypeInfo's 'interfaces' member as INTERFACE_PCIE_DEVICE, I don't know if that's enough.